# Composer and custom controls

Tags: c#, episerver

How can I get PageLink to the current page if I need it in the custom control within a composer block. If I use CurrentPage (member of PropertyDataControl that is my base class for the custom control), I get PageData that refers to the composer element, not to the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I managed to find a solution. In case somebody was facing the same problem, here's the way to go:

```
protected PageData CurrentParentPage
        {
            get
            {
                var currentParentPage = PageReference.ParseUrl(Page.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri);
                if(!PageReference.IsNullOrEmpty(currentParentPage))
                {
                    return currentParentPage.GetPageFromReference();
                }
                return null;
            }
        }
```

This should be put int the control class